# Create DynamoDB Global Secondary Index after table creation in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to create GSI on an existing table programmatically from java? I know that its possible while creating a new table using

```
dynamoDB.createTable(new CreateTableRequest().withGlobalSecondaryIndexes(index));
```

I also know that it is possible to create index after creating table from web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdate way of doing this, as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdate.html

It should look something like this

```
CreateGlobalSecondaryIndexAction action = CreateGlobalSecondaryIndexAction
                .builder()
                .indexName("index-name")
                .keySchema(theSchema)
                .build();
GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdate index = GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdate
                .builder()
                .create(action)
                .build();
UpdateTableRequest request = UpdateTableRequest
                .builder()
                .tableName("table-name")
                .globalSecondaryIndexUpdates(index)
                .build();
dynamoDbClient.updateTable(request);
```

Comment: the dynamoDbClient is of type AmazonDynamoDB and not DynamoDB.